# Using find() with multiple filters Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I've been trying to understand how to use multiple filters in the find() method for SQL.

I've tried many ways but the best I've come up with is

```
$entity_table->find(array('title = ? AND id != ?', $entity_title, $entity_id));
```

but still not getting the correct result. Also, unfortunately, I can't find any topics online on this matter. Is it possible to handle multiple filters in the find() method?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my SQL was off (I thought that might have been it) and I had a little mishap with syntax. For clarity, multiple WHERE clauses can be added to the `find()` method. Here's the correct way that includes `NOT`:

```
$tbl_obj = $entity_table->find(array('title = ? AND NOT id = ?', $entity_title, $entity_id));
```